# Product part Query (BOM)

Tags: db2, cte, recursive

I'm using DB2 V7 and i have a product table like below :

```
select * from product;

Product |Component|Quantity |Line number|
--------+---------+---------+------------
Product1|Part1    |1        |1
Product1|Product2 |2        |2    
Product1|Part2    |1        |3
Product2|Part3    |4        |1
Product2|Part4    |4        |2
Product9|Part8    |5        |1
```

What I want is to perform a SELECT that return all child components that compose a product. The desired Query should return a result like below..

```
Product |Component|Quantity|Line number|BOM Level
--------+---------+--------+-----------+---------
Product1|Part1    |1       |1          |1
Product1|Part3    |8       |2          |2
Product1|Part4    |8       |3          |2
Product1|Part2    |1       |4          |1
Product2|Part3    |4       |1          |1
Product2|Part4    |4       |2          |1
Product9|Part8    |5       |1          |1
```

Comment: What is "Line Number"? Where the value of `4` in resultset is taken from?

Comment: Does the maximal nesting level is not specified?

Comment: Three to four level should be enough..

Comment: 4 stand for the position of the component in the product

Comment: *Three to four level should be enough* If four levels max you may use simple 4-part union. *4 stand for the position of the component in the product* I.e. it is simple ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: Have you tried the BOM query example from the manual?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes the "Example 2: Summarized explosion" worked great, but need some modification ; I added a table to tell wether the product is an assembly or not , if yes then it would return all sub component if not it would only return him self..

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=df91e408a7a0e20bcdb4cc81f0c7d838

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL the below query gives correct result it seems. Try to adapt...

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte (sProduct, sComponent, sQuantity, Product, Component, Quantity, HaveChilds) 
AS ( SELECT Product, 
            Component, 
            Quantity, 
            Product, 
            Component, 
            Quantity,
            EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM product p2
                     WHERE p1.Component = p2.Product )
     FROM product p1
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                        FROM product p3
                        WHERE p1.Product = p3.Component )
  UNION ALL
     SELECT cte.sProduct, 
            cte.sComponent, 
            cte.sQuantity, 
            p1.Product, 
            p1.Component, 
            cte.Quantity * p1.Quantity,
            EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM product p2
                     WHERE p1.Component = p2.Product )
     FROM cte, product p1
     WHERE cte.Component = p1.Product
       AND cte.HaveChilds = 1 
)
SELECT sProduct Product, 
       Component, 
       Quantity, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sProduct 
                          ORDER BY Component) Line_Number
FROM cte
WHERE HaveChilds = 0
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0398b034750de73e10bc43529d8579c6) (source data is slightly changed, 3rd level added).

This fiddle while using DB2 (and removing RECURSIVE keyword) gives empty result (maybe DB2 requires different approaches to working with boolean values?).